# What happens to sql views, if database is moved to another server

Tags: mysql, view, rdbms

I have created a view in my current database. But now I'm moving the database to another server. Normally I'm taking the dump, but not sure about views.

Will they come when I import the dump and work as per the view?
Or
I need to create view again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dump you create with `mysqldump` will contain the `CREATE VIEW` statements.

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) says:

> mysqldump requires at least the SELECT privilege for dumped tables, SHOW VIEW for dumped views, TRIGGER for dumped triggers, and LOCK TABLES if the --single-transaction option is not used. Certain options might require other privileges as noted in the option descriptions.

Comment: this mean the views will work as normal even I changed the server and import the dump? @simbabque

Comment: I guess. You need to connect to the new server of course, but basically a view is like a table to the client, so why would they not? Just go ahead and try. Make a test DB, add a view, dump, import, query.

Comment: Yeah, I will try like this